# uses-sdk tag not showing on android manifest file

Tags: android

i am using `<uses-sdk >` in manifest file.
After exporting apk , when I  decompile my apk and check manifest file. and i wonder to see there is no any `<uses-sdk>` tag in manifest,So during exporting apk Is this tag removed automatically, Why this is happen , i have been checked with several apk and getting same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got two links which show that it has been removed in the new version of apktool

https://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/issues/detail?id=390

https://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/issues/detail?id=366

pls check

Answer (score 0):

most decompilers don't give all the information of the app. Some would require payment to get access to those / get the complete etc.

Comment: I am using apk tool and except uses-tag it is showing all the details of all apk which i have been checked